# Correct way to pass parameters from custom URL protocol handler to Windows program

Tags: javascript, browser, uri, protocols

I have created a custom URL protocol handler ([I used this guide to help me](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).  It works like this:

`protocol:" <data_string_1> <data_string_2>"`

This works great in Google Chrome.  My program gets the following parameters when this is called:

```
param_1: protocol:
param_2: <data_string_1>
param_2: <data_string_2>
```

However, in Firefox, the entire procedure call is put into param_1, like so:

```
param_1: protocol:%22%20<data_string_1>%20<data_string_2>
```

In Internet Explorer 11, the parameters are parsed the same way as Google Chrome, but there is a 507 character limit to work against!

Does anybody know of a good way to handle all of these cases and still keep my sanity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there isn't a good way to handle this except to write different code for each browser you want to support.